# xampp blocking remote external connections

Tags: apache, xampp, windows-10

I have read several questions here and still nothing is working.

I am trying to access my test site from a remote computer (either network or wan but i need wan eventually)

I just re-downloaded the newest XAMPP for windows 10.

I can go to localhost (also the other 3 names I setup in the host file to redirect to localhost) and of course 127.0.0.1 (localhost).

If I try and use my ip address of the computer or someone else trys my ip address on their computer, we get page cant be found (from chrome)

If I check apache access logs I see nothing about an access attempt.

Netstat -a shows these two records

```
TCP  0.0.0.0:80
TCP  0.0.0.0:443
TCP  [::]:80
TCP  [::]:443
```

I have gone to Windows Firewall -> Advanced Settings -> Inbound rule.  Here it shows that appache has 2 rules, one for UDP and one for TCP allowing all ports.

I have gone to my rounter and port forwarded 80 & 443 (which is what xampp is running on) and still nothing

I even have put my computer in a DMZ.  I also turned off the windows firewall.  (all back on after testing of course this is dangerous).

Xampp has no locationmatch in xampp-http.conf like other questions.

My vhost file has the directory setup like this:

```
 <Directory "C:/Users/username/Desktop/git repos/stats-website">
   AllowOverride All
   Order Allow,Deny
   Allow from all
   Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is my testing rig and I am now testing an API that is being accessed externally before I send it to the production server.  I have been at this for 2 days and out of all possibilities

**UPDATE**

I have solved the issue somewhat.  I can now get to it from everything except localhost or 127.0.0.1

In httpd.conf I changed it from just Listen 80 to Listen pcipaddress:80.  I thought listen 80 defaulted to binding on more than just localhost

```
# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to 
# prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
#
Listen 192.168.1.241:80
#Listen 80
```

How do I do it so it works both localhost and also remote connections?

Comment: Hard to say which part is failing you. Can you try run netstat -an from your console to see which application is listening to what port? It may help figuring out the root cause.

Comment: sorry meant to add that.  I see "[::]:80" and "0.0.0.0:80"